# Do all kinds of newlines get converted to \r\n when submitted through a html form?

Tags: html, forms, unicode, newline, enctype

The [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#form-content-type) from w3c states the following for forms of `enctype=application/x-www-form-urlencoded`:

> This is the default content type. Forms submitted with this content
>   type must be encoded as follows:
>
> 1) Control names and values are escaped. Space characters are replaced by `+', and then reserved characters are escaped as described
>   in [RFC1738], section 2.2: Non-alphanumeric characters are replaced by`
>   %HH', a percent sign and two hexadecimal digits representing the
>   ASCII code of the character. **Line breaks are represented as "CR LF"
>   pairs (i.e., `%0D%0A')**.
>
> 2) The control names/values are listed in the order they appear in the document. The name is separated from the value by `=' and
>   name/value pairs are separated from each other by`&'.

There are a few kinds of line terminators in Unicode. Namely:

```
 LF:    Line Feed, U+000A
 VT:    Vertical Tab, U+000B
 FF:    Form Feed, U+000C
 CR:    Carriage Return, U+000D
 CR+LF: CR (U+000D) followed by LF (U+000A)
 NEL:   Next Line, U+0085
 LS:    Line Separator, U+2028
 PS:    Paragraph Separator, U+2029
```

Are all of these converted to CR LF (`\r\n`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are all of these converted to CR LF (\r\n)?

Nope. The HTML4 spec here is unclear on what a line break is, but what browsers do, and what HTML5 has gone on to [standardise](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#constructing-form-data-set) is that only CR and LF are involved:

> replace every occurrence of a "CR" (U+000D) character not followed by a "LF" (U+000A) character, and every occurrence of a "LF" (U+000A) character not preceded by a "CR" (U+000D) character, by a two-character string consisting of a U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN "CRLF" (U+000A) character pair

(IE doesn't quite conform to this exactly, as it treats LFCR as a single newline. But it's close enough.)